# PytestCollectionWarning: наследование от класса страницы в тестах

Tags: python, selenium, объекты, pytest, page

Пишу тесты для работы с веб-страницами, и меня утомляет каждый раз инициализировать новый объект страницы в каждом из методов тестового класса, и передавать в каждый метод экземпляр webdriver (selenium):

```
class TestCheck(object):            
    def test_1(self, driver):   
        page = HomePage(driver)
        page.open_page1()    

    def test_2(self, driver):   
        page = HomePage(driver)
        page.open_page2()

...
```

Попытался наследоваться от класса страницы и использовать родительские методы внутри тестового класса, однако при запуске тестов pytest выдает PytestCollectionWarning:

```
class TestCheck(HomePage):
    def __init__(self):         
        super().__init__(self)  

    def test_new(self):         
        self.open_page()
```

> PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'TestSubClass'
>   because it has a **init** constructor

По этой ошибке удалось найти только инфу в документации pytest, как типичный пример ситуации, в которой срабатывает данный warning, однако нет ни слова о том, как исправить такую ситуацию.
Каким образом я могу передавать в тестовый класс методы родительского класса, не объявляя каждый раз экземпляр страницы в каждом из тестовых методов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого прекрасно подходят фикстуры. Примеры:

#### Инициализация атрибута заново для каждого теста:

Если нужен атрибут, который надо заново создавать для каждого теста, для инициализации лучше всего подходит фикстура-метод класса:

```
class TestCheck:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def init_page(self, driver):
        self.page = HomePage(driver)

    def test_1(self):
        self.page.open_page1()

    def test_2(self):
        self.page.open_page2()
```

#### Инициализация атрибута для класса:

Если атрибут нужно инициализировать один раз для тестового класса, используй фикстуру со скоупом `class`:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
def init_page(request, driver):
    request.cls.page = HomePage(driver)


class TestCheck:

    def test_1(self):
        self.page.open_page1()

    def test_2(self):
        self.page.open_page2()
```

#### Инициализация атрибута для ограниченного набора классов:

В примере выше, параметр `autouse=True` будет выполнять фикстуру для всех классов. Если `self.page` нужна только в `TestCheck`, но, к примеру, бесполезна в `TestFizz`, то используй маркеры вместо `autouse`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def init_page(request, driver):
    request.cls.page = HomePage(driver)


@pytest.mark.usefixtures('init_page')
class TestCheck:

    def test_1(self):
        self.page.open_page1()

    def test_2(self):
        self.page.open_page2()


class TestFizz:
    ...
```

#### Инициализация для тестовой сессии:

Если объект нужно переиспользовать в нескольких тестовых классах (к примеру, у тебя один инстанс страницы `HomePage` для всех тестов), то я обычно использую такую конструкцию: делаю две фикстуры, одна со скоупом `session`, где происходит инициализация, другая со скоупом `class`, где происходит только присваивание:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def page(driver):
    page = HomePage(driver)
    return page


@pytest.fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
def set_page(request, page):
    request.cls.page = page


class TestCheck:
    def test_1(self):
        self.page.open_page1()

    def test_2(self):
        self.page.open_page2()
```